# Accessing FingerprintManager from Nativescript

Tags: nativescript

I am fairly new to Nativescript and I need to develop a plugin that access the fingerprint/touchid on Android and iOS (the plugins I have found does not do what I need), and I am starting with Android because that is known land for me. But already I hit a wall...

I can make a variable like this:

```
private camera: android.hardware.Camera;
```

But this fails with "Namespace 'android.hardware' has no exported member 'fingerprint':

```
private fingerprintManager: android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager;
```

I wonder if it has to do with a version of the Android SDK I am compiling against, or what it is? How do I fix this?

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [`tns-platform-declarations`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-platform-declarations) you will need to use the declarations generated against API 23 and above (as the [FingerprintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager) was introduced in API 23)

```
npm i tns-platform-declarations --save-dev
```

reference.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/ios.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="./node_modules/tns-platform-declarations/android-23.d.ts" />
```

Note that the file name is **android-23.d.ts**

You will also need to have **Android SDK 23 or above installed in your SDK Manager**.
[Here is a sample application](https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues-2018-II/tree/master/test/fingerPrintManager) demonstrating the above technique

Comment: Thank you, I googled it and found some documentation on it also :) However now I get a lot of "android-support-23.d.ts:31459:19 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'ViewStubCompat'" errors?

Comment: Deleting all "node_modules" and "hooks" and "platforms" folders fixed it.